# Comparing photos from the directory with an excel table and entering them into a new excel table

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a directory with about 250 photos whose names are defined by numbers. Example: "**12341233.jpg**". **12341233.jpg** indicates the ID of the item displayed on the site. Some items have 2 or more photos, in which case **"-1", "-2", "-3", "-4"** is added to the photo name. Which means that if **Article 12341233** has **3 photos** in the directory, there will be 3 photos under the names "**12341233.jpg**", "**12341233-1.jpg**", "**12341233-2.jpg**".

In the excel table, which is stored in the same directory as the photos, we have the row **Name of the Article (row C)** and the row **Picture 1 (row K)**, **Picture 2 (row L)**, **Picture 3 (row M)** and **Picture 4 (row N)**.

What the script should do is compare the names of the photos from the directory with the names in the excel table (without the **.jpg** extension) and if there are names in the excel table and it does not find them in the directory, it creates a **new excel table** and writes the names of the missing photos there (Picture 1 , Picture 2, Picture 3, Picture 4 ). If they happen to have 2 photos in the directory while 2 are not found, in line Image 3, Image 4 only writes a red background color. The same applies if there is, for example, picture 2 and picture 4 in the directory in the excel table, the background color is red marked by row Picture 1 and Picture 3.

```
import os
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

photo_dir = "";
excel_dir = "";
new_excel_dir = "";

wb_table = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_dir)
sheet_table = wb_table.active

wb_new_table = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet_new_table = wb_new_table.active

photos = [f.split(".")[0] for f in os.listdir(photo_dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(photo_dir, f))]

suffixes = ["-1", "-2", "-3", "-4"]
fill = PatternFill(start_color="00FF00", end_color="00FF00", fill_type="solid")

for row in sheet_table.iter_rows(min_row=2, min_col=3, max_col=3, values_only=True):
    photo_name = row[0].split(".")[0]
    
    if photo_name in photos:
        sheet_new_table.append([photo_name])

        if any(suffix in photo_name for suffix in suffixes):
            for i in range(2, 6):
                sheet_new_table.cell(row=sheet_new_table.max_row, column=i).fill = fill

wb_new_table.save(new_excel_dir)
```

When I run the script I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*******\test.py", line 26, in <module>
    photo_name = row[0].split(".")[0]
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Can someone help me with this script, if I'm wrong somewhere, correct me and explain. Thanks to all

Comment: Please, post the full traceback you get, not just the error description

Comment: Clearly *row[0] == None* so you'll need to figure out why that might be

Comment: That is an empty cell. You use `values_only=True`, so row is tuple of row values

Comment: What is your advice to solve the problem? @buran

Comment: Is it reasonable to have empty cell? If yes - check that `row[0]` in not None before split, handle the case of empty cell accordingly. Also check `os.path.splitext` for proper file name manipulation

Comment: I'm new to python, I'm trying to understand you as best as possible but it's not working. I hope you understand me
 @buran

Comment: You need to account for empty cells, e.g. validate that `row[0]` is not `None`.